# GWT - Global clickHandler to work on HTML class attribute elements?

Tags: gwt, widget, html

I have a button which I add an HTML class and the java class clickHandler to:

```java
Button someButton = new Button();
someButton.getElement().setClassName("someClass");
someButton.addClickHandler(this);
```

Then my java class clickHandler looks like:

```java
public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
    Widget sender = (Widget) event.getSource();
    if(sender == someOtherWidget){
        ...
    }else if(...){
    ...
}
```

What I would like to do is add something to the clickHandler which will make it do something if the sender widger has  the `someClass` HTML class. Something like:

```java
else if(sender.getClassName().equals("someClass")){
    doSomething();
}
```

However, the widget doesn't have getClassName(). Anyone have a suggestion about how to get the HTML class applied on the widget? Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. This:

```java
else if(sender.getClassName().equals("someClass")){
    doSomething();
}
```

Should be this:

```java
else if(sender.getElement().getClassName().equals("someClass")){
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Is this working?  I would have expected to use `String#equals` ... I wouldn't expect "==" to work for string comparisons.

Comment: @AndyKing: Very good point. I discovered that problem as well after getting the first part to work and didn't even think about coming back here to correct this answer. Updating the answer (and question) now, thanks.